# VBA Excel: Non-Active Sheet and Unknown Number of Rows. If cell contains value, perfom calculation and insert new value into cell on same row

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement, worksheet, vba

I have tried my best to search for the answer but can't get what I'm looking for. I'm very new to VBA so may be going wrong in several places here . . .

I'm creating a data formatter that processes data with a different numbers of records (rows) each time it is used. Data will be on non-active sheet. First row has headings. I've successfully used similar code to the code below to identify rows with certain data on it and clear the contents of other cells on that row.

The reason I refer to column E is because it is the only column that has data in every record. I then have to find the rows that have a value in column BU, then multiply that value by 20 and insert the result in column BX of the same row.

I keep getting Run-time Error 13 but don't understand as it's simply a number with 2 decimal places in cell BU, and currently there is nothing in BX.

```
Sub CalcTotalLTA()

Dim i As Variant

'counts the no. of rows in E and loops through all
For i = 1 To Sheets("Input").Range("E2", Sheets("Input").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'Identifies rows where columns BU has a value
If Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 73).Value <> "" Then

'calculate Total LTA

Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 76).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 73).Value * 20

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to change `Sheets("Input").Range("E2", Sheets("Input").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`.  With data in just row 1 and/or 2 it returns 1048575.  So if your data table is empty it will operate on all rows in the sheet.  Maybe try `sheets("Input").cells(sheets("Input").rows.count,5).end(xlup).row` instead which will give you the last row containing data in column E (column 5).

Comment: If you found one of the answers to be helpful or answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely having an issue because `Application.Sheets` holds both sheet types, which are `Charts` and `Worksheets`. `Application.Sheets` does not have a `.Range()` property.

Replace all instances of `Sheets()` with `Worksheets()`.

```
Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 76).Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 73).Value * 20
```

Even better:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Input")

..

ws.Cells(i,76).Value = ws.Cells(i,73).Value * 20
```

**Exclude Header Row From Range**

```
Public Function rngExcludeHeaders(rng As Range) As Range
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.rows.count - 1, rng.Columns.count)
    Set rngExcludeHeaders = rng
End Function
```

usage:

```
Dim MyRange as Range
Set MyRange = rngExcludeHeaders(ws.UsedRange)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I've updated one of the tags to 'Worksheet'. I've tried both suggestions above and I'm still having Run-time error 13 on the following line: ws.Cells(i, 76).Value = ws.Cells(i, 73).Value * 20

Comment: try `Debug.Print ws.Cells(i,73).Value * 20` on it's own line and step through the debug. If it errors on that then your data is likely the culprit.  It may be a number stored as text, or it may have "quotes" around it, or it may have a leading 'apostrophe mucking it up.

Comment: I tried putting this where you state but I get a syntax error. I put this at the start of the whole and stepped into, and 'True' was returned in the Immediate window at the bottom. What do I do now?

Comment: I just tried removing the header row and the code has run fine!!! The mismatch was because of the string in the first row. I just need to figure out how to edit my code to ignore the header row.

Comment: Thanks. Instead I just changed the initial value of I to 2: "For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2", ws.Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count". This works but misses the last row!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcTotalLTA()

    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Input")
        For i = 1 To .Range("E2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Row
            If .Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
                .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(i, 3) * 20
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I have changed:

- Adding Option Explicit on top
- I have used With Worksheets("Input") to make your code more understandable.
- Furthermore, I suppose you do not need `Rows.Count` but `.Row`
- I have changed `76` and `73` to `3` and `6` to avoid some scrolling to the right, thus be careful when you use it over your workbook.
- Removed `.Value` as far as it is the default one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the code certainly looks neater. I'm a bit confused about changing 73 and 76 to 3 and 6. I thought the 73 and 76 indicated the column I was referring to? The file I am working with is a template and goes right up to column 'CA'. I was using 73 and 76 to refer to columns BU and BX . . .

Comment: @CodeyMcCode - just change 73 and 76 back. I used them, cos I did not want to scroll right to `BU` and `BX`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to input from @Adam Vincent and @Vityata, and some other research (the reason why I'm solving this myself, hope that's not bad etiquette) I've found the solution. Starting the index 'i' at 2 and adding 1 at the end avoids the header row text and includes the last row too:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcTotalLTA()

Dim i As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Input")

'counts the no. of rows in E and loops through all
For i = 2 To ws.Range("E2", ws.Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1

'Identifies rows where columns BU has a value
If ws.Cells(i, 73).Value <> "" Then

'calculate Total LTA

ws.Cells(i, 76).NumberFormat = "0.00"
ws.Cells(i, 76).Value = ws.Cells(i, 73).Value * 20

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. If the other answers were helpful in determining your final solution, it is good etiquette to upvote them.